# ¿Qué significa o que es KT_escapeAttribute(KT_getFullUri()) en ASP?

Tags: sql-server, asp

Estoy intentando leer un codigo de asp que no fue creado por mi, pero es complicado nunca habia usado asp con vbscript, entonces hay alguna dudas sobre esto por ejemplo que es:

```
 - KT_escapeAttribute(KT_getFullUri()),
   - Response.Write("KT_even "),
    <%
   - Dim tfi_listrs_pacientes: Set tfi_listrs_pacientes = new TFI_TableFilter
    tfi_listrs_pacientes.Init MM_oConn_STRING, "tfi_listrs_pacientes"
    tfi_listrs_pacientes.addColumn "expediente", "STRING_TYPE", "expediente", "%"
    tfi_listrs_pacientes.addColumn "nombrePaciente", "STRING_TYPE", "nombrePaciente", "%"
    tfi_listrs_pacientes.addColumn "sexo", "STRING_TYPE", "sexo", "="
    tfi_listrs_pacientes.addColumn "edad", "NUMERIC_TYPE", "edad", "="
    tfi_listrs_pacientes.Execute()
    %>
```

Me podrían orientar en esto por favor, ya busque información pero no logo comprender.

Comment: buscando en internet directamente no encontré nada, pero por lo que sí encuentro, me da la impresión de que es una librería

Comment: Así es, también busque pero no encuentro algo especifico, muchas gracias por tu comentario.